# Margin menu in IE

Tags: html, css

Faced with the problem. Made a menu on Jquery. All browsers good show site, except of course Internet Explorer. Tell me, what can be done to remove the padding in IE, the site address http://edusf.ru/project/

Comment: The padding on which element?

Comment: menu, here's a screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14694565/bad.png

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  Check out this JSfiddle; a copy of your code.  The copy doesn't have the padding problem, but your site does.  http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/XaQ4F/9/

Answer (score 1):

First you are missing a doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Your page shows up in Quirks mode in IE9. Once you do that, your document will be in IE9 standard mode and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: The fact that the very page is written in asp and paste the html exactly as I do not know. Here is my code, but still works with a space menu: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14694565/page%20code.txt